# CoffeeScript: lazy evaluation without using parenthesis

Tags: coffeescript

I am trying to create a sort of global, singleton object in my CoffeeScript code:

```
window.MyLib = 
  Foos: {}
  Bars: {}
  Client: ->
    @_client ||= (
      someVar = 'foo'
      new ExpensiveClient(someVar)
    )

# ...


MyLib.Client.performSomeAction()
```

However, the code actually requires me to do this:

```
MyLib.Client().performSomeAction()
```

How can I get around this problem of implementing a lazy instantiation without needing to use parenthesis to call it as a function?

**Update:** Alternatively, if there was a way to implement a sort of "method missing", the `Client` function could return an object that delegates the responsibilities to the actual client, but only instantiate it when it needs to.

Comment: So you want to run that function every time you access `Client`?

Comment: Same as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11587231/479863)? Or at least the same answer perhaps.

Comment: @phenomnomnominal Yes, in order to prevent `Client` from being instantiated from the beginning, wrapping it in a function and only instantiating when it is called for the first time prevents an unnecessary `ExpensiveClient` from being created if it doesn't need to be.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something like this:

```
lazyGet = (obj, name, property) ->
  Object.defineProperty obj, name, get: property

window.MyLib = do ->
  @_client = null

  Foos: {}
  Bars: {}

  lazyGet this, 'Client', ->
    @_client ||= (
      someVar = 'foo'
      new ExpensiveClient someVar
    )
```

Comment: Upvote for creativity, but not something I'd like to encounter in a production environment.

Comment: That looks close to what I'm trying to do, but can you explain this line in a little more detail? `Object.defineProperty obj, name, get: property`

Comment: [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) is just another way for defining properties on an object. Part of it allows you to specify how `get` and `set` work on that property. Here we are simply assigning the "Singleton" function to the `get` accessor, so that it gets called if and when the property is accessed. Like @MichielKalkman said, it might raise a few eyebrows, so if you do use it, comment lots. Also, `lazyGet` probably doesn't quite sum up what's happening.