# Object not being passed by reference (CoffeeScript)

Tags: javascript, class, reference, coffeescript

I have two classes, one which holds and manages data and one which makes decisions based on the data

```
module.exports = class Data
    constructor: () ->
         @stuff = 
             foo: 42
             bar: 'something'
```

and in another file

```
module.exports = class Mutator
    constructor: (Data) ->
         @foo = Data.foo
```

and in a main file

```
Data = require './Data'
Mutator = require './Mutator'

module.exports = class Main
     constructor: () ->
         @data = new Data()
         @mutator = new Mutator(@data)
```

the problem I'm having is that `@data` does not seem to be being passed by reference

In main

```
console.log @Mutator.foo # 42
@data.foo = '24'
console.log @Mutator.foo # still 42
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@data` is being passed by reference but you're throwing that reference way when you pull out the `Data.foo` value here:

```
@foo = Data.foo
```

Your `Data` is the same as your `@data` but `@foo` is just the value of `Data.foo`. You'd need to hold onto `Data` rather than `Data.foo`:

```
class Mutator
    constructor: (Data) ->
         @data = Data
```

and then look at `@mutator.data.foo`. You could probably use [`defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to define a getter for `foo` and thus hide the `data` part and make `@mutator.foo` work. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11592890/479863) for some notes on how this would work.

Comment: would it work if `foo` were an object `{}` and I passed it like this, `@mutator = new Mutator(@data.foo)` and then set it like this `@foo = foo`?

Comment: As long as people said `@data.foo.x = 6` rather than `@data.foo = { x: 6 }` so that the reference didn't change.