# How can I make a property of a class case-insensitive?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, object, coffeescript

In CoffeeScript, let's say I've got the following:

```
class Greeter
    message: ->
        greeting = switch @gender
            when 'male' then 'Sir'
            when 'female' then 'Madame'
            else 'Unknown'

        "Hello #{greeting}!"

greeter = new Greeter
greeter.gender = 'Male'
alert greeter.message()
```

This currently alerts `Hello Unknown!` when I want it to output `Hello Sir!`.

How do I make it so that the `Greeter` class will lowercase the `@gender` instance variable so that the correct output is achieved? I don't want to just lowercase it in the `message` method, but rather, all throughout an Instance of the Class. This is so that it works in other methods too.

I think I'm missing something very basic but I just can't seem to wrap my head around it.

**NOTE:** To those saying I got the capitalization wrong for "Male". Yes, I purposely did that. I'd like the class to *automatically* lowercase `gender` in all cases, before using it. So the user can get the capitalization wrong and it *still* works.

The reason is that I'd eventually like to extrapolate this to other situations, rather than just those dealing with case-insensitivity issues.

Some people have mentioned JavaScript Getters and Setters, which are relatively new and therefore not supported in all major browsers. I'll take a look at those. I'm somewhat familiar with them through Ruby.

Comment: What does it write when you change `#{greeting}` too `#{gender}`

Comment: Then it says it is not defined. Otherwise if I used `#{@gender}` then it says "Hello Male!" as expected.

Comment: @Gary I'm going to change the title here; you really care about the case sensitivity, not the value of the `@gender`

Comment: Well this is not specific to case-sensitivity; I'm more generally looking for a way to change variables passed to an Instance. Although I guess yes, in this specific case I gave the example as a case-sensitivity issue because that is the easiest way to show an example.

Comment: Ah, yes I see what you mean. OK I can come up with a better answer and title then.

Comment: Yes, I now know I should probably have worded my question better because there seems to be lots of confusion regarding it. The example of case-sensitivity was, in hindsight, a poor example, because providing a solution seems really trivial at first. But this has led me to JS Getters and Setters, which seem promising.

Answer (score 2):

`Male` is not `male`. Try normalize your string as lower case:

```
message: ->
    greeting = switch @gender.toLowerCase()
        when 'male' then 'Sir'
        when 'female' then 'Madame'
        else 'Unknown'
```

---

If necessary, you might want to encapsulate the call to lowercase in some property *getter*: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11592890/2363712 Something like that:

```
class Greeter
    constructor: ->
        Object.defineProperty  @, 'gender',
            get: ->
                return @_gender
            set: (value) ->
                @_gender = value.toLowerCase()

    message: ->
        greeting = switch @gender
            when 'male' then 'Sir'
            when 'female' then 'Madame'
            else 'Unknown'

        "Hello #{greeting}!"
```

For this to work, your run-time environment must support [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) 
See [that table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Object.defineProperty) for a quick lookup of supported browsers.

Comment: No this is not what I want, though. I want `@gender` to be lowercased for ALL of the class's methods, not just one.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at JavaScript getters and setters to see if they are fully supported yet.

Comment: @Gary See my edit for a working version (tested on node.js) If you want to go that way, you will be restricted to browser supporting `Object.defineProperty` (part of EMCAScript 5, if I'm not too wrong).

Answer (score 0):

```
coffee> 
  class Greeter
    message: =>
        greeting =
          if /^male/i.test(@gender) then 'Sir'
          else if /^female/i.test(@gender) then 'Madame'
          else 'Unknown'

        "Hello #{greeting}!"

greeter = new Greeter
greeter.gender = 'Male'
greeter.message()

'Hello Sir!'
coffee> greeter.gender  = 'female' 
'female'
coffee> greeter.message()
'Hello Madame!'
coffee> greeter.gender  = 'smizmar' 
'smizmar'
coffee> greeter.message()
'Hello Unknown!'
coffee>
```

So that's the simple way to do it, but it doesn't change the value stored. To do that, you'll need to use [Object.defineProperty (SO answer about it)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587231/coffeescript-getter-setter-in-object-initializers):

```
Function::property = (prop, desc) ->
  Object.defineProperty @prototype, prop, desc

class Greeter
  constructor: () ->
  @property 'gender',
    get: -> "#{@ciGender}"
    set: (v) -> @ciGender = v.toLowerCase()
  message: ->
    greeting = switch @ciGender
        when 'male' then 'Sir'
        when 'female' then 'Madame'
        else 'Unknown'

    "Hello #{greeting}!"
```